# Set autofocus input not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create the input by this code:

```js
 self._hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    self._hiddenInput.type = 'text';

    // self._hiddenInput.setAttribute('autofocus', 'autofocus');
    self._hiddenInput.setAttribute('Id', hiddenInput);
    self._hiddenInput.style.cssText = 'width:' + self._width + 'px;' +
      'height:' + self._height + 'px;' +
      'left:' + self._pointHiddenInput.x + 'px;' +
      'top:' + self._pointHiddenInput.y + 'px;' +
      'position:absolute;' +
      'pointerEvents:none;' +
      'zIndex:0;' +
      'opacity:0;';

    // append this to document
    document.body.appendChild(self._hiddenInput);
```

and then I set focus to this input by method self._hiddenInput.focus() but it's not working. I don't know why.

What is wrong here?.

Comment: `hiddenInput is not defined`

Comment: is that your full code ?

Comment: `self._hiddenInput.setAttribute('autofocus', 'autofocus');` this will work

Comment: @Durga if i set autofocus attribute. I remove and add new input, the new input not autofocus anymore. :(

Answer (score 0):

did you try self._hiddenInput.focus() after appending the element?

Comment: Yes sir, after appending to body i call this method

Comment: This code beside there is my full code. I just call the focus in other method in other ts file, but after method create this input